# Set working directory to mapped network drive in BATCH mode

Tags: r

I'm having issues on windows with R failing when changing the working directory to a mapped network drive (e.g. \Share\Folder mapped to Z:) in batch mode.  If I run the same script in an interactive console I don't have any issues.  I am accomplishing this by running R.exe with the script specified inside of a windows batch (.bat) file.  The .bat file contains the following.

```
"C:\RRO\R-3.2.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:/Scripts/Rscript.R"
```

The error is simply...

```
> setwd( 'Z:/' ) 
 Error in setwd("Z:/") : cannot change working directory
```

I'd be open to a different approach entirely for scheduling these scripts via the windows task scheduler if that helps avoid the issue.  The reason for mapping the drive is that I need to supply some credentials in order to access it, which is done automatically when it is mapped, but can test to see if that's not the case in R if anyone knows how.

Comment: Could not reproduce on win7+domain. may depends on credentials of user your using ... what system is on server?

Comment: @HubertL I'm connecting to a restricted group folder hosted by Windows server over a VPN

Comment: You could use the full path to the drive. Open command prompt, enter `net use` to see the full paths to the mapped drives. Then use "//volume/path/" of the remote drive for the working directory.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help with your question.
I duplicated the problem with no errors by using Rscript command instead of a CMD BATCH

my R code which I saved as a script (test1.R)

```
library(openxlsx)

setwd("P:/Records/Indexing Operations/Indexing Data Analysis/Daily Reports")
my.data = read.xlsx("FSI Daily Project Status Report - 18 Mar 2016.xlsx", sheet = 1) 
setwd("C:/Users/golieth/Documents/")

png(filename = "test.png", width = 500, height = 350 )
plot(my.data$Total.Images, my.data$Completed.Images.A,
 main = Sys.time())
dev.off()
```

Note I change the directory 2 times in this file. Once to access data on a mapped network drive and a 2nd to save the image to the computer.  I put a timestamp of the current time as the main plot title so you can run the batch file repeatedly and verify it works

my batch file

```
cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\i386
Rscript C:\Users\golieth\Documents\test1.R
```

Note:  On the batch file if your code relies on 32 bit you need to change the directory of your R program (cd) to the R 32bit program.  Same with R64.  Next the Rscript should reference where you have saved your .R file

Finally, and this might be stating the obvious but make sure you are connected to your VPN before running the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a batch file with

```
cd Z:\<Destination>
Z:
RScript "C:/Scripts/Rscript.R"
```

This will enable Windows to change to the directory with all credentials and then start R within that directory. So the working dir. is the location from where R is started. Doing so requires that `"C:\RRO\R-3.2.1\bin\"` is part of your `PATH` variable.

Good luck!

Comment: I'll give this a try

Comment: This works, I'll award the bounty if no better answers (i.e. one that lets me change to the directly outside of shell) arise

Comment: I have an idea about this. But I don't know if that will work. Try to open or "echo" a file with the `system("echo "Z:\testfile.txt")` command within your R script. This should connect to the network drive. Then change to there with `setwd` . This utilizes first the bach mechanism if it were a windows .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

When writing a <kbd>.bat</kbd> file, remember that `cd` is not used to change drive letters. To change drive letters you simply enter the name of the drive letter, which should be done prior to issuing the final `cd` to the working directory.

Like this:

<kbd>sample.bat</kbd>

```
z:
cd z:\your\working\directory\
C:\RRO\R-3.2.1\bin\Rscript.exe C:/Scripts/Rscript.R
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save the files locally in your code, and use `file.copy` in your code to copy the files over to your network drive. Also try replacing the path in `file.copy` the network drive letter by the full network address name eg. `\\....\.....\`